# Unnamed components from shallow rendering a component using render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

New to testing with enzyme and typescript. I'm trying to test a component that uses an open-source component to render a progress bar.

Initially, I had a passing test for "does it render a progress bar" however as soon as I passed in children to be rendered, I couldn't get the subsequent test to pass and my initial test started failing. The progress bar component uses react render props to render the children.

Here is the render method of my component

```
render () {
      return (
        <ProgressBar
          percent={75}
          filledBackground="linear-gradient(to right, #fefb72, #f0bb31)"
        >
          {this.state.steps.map(function (item: CaseStep) {
            return (
              <Step key={item.Id} transition="scale">
              {({ accomplished }: StepProps) => (
                <div>
                  {item.StepName}
                </div>
              )}
            </Step>
            )
          })}
        </ProgressBar>
      )
  }
```

and these are the tests in question

```
    let mountedComponent
    beforeEach(() => {
        mountedComponent = shallow(<CaseProgress {...testProps}/>);
    })

    it('renders a progress bar',() => {
        let progressBars = mountedComponent.find('ProgressBar')
        expect(progressBars.length).toEqual(1)
    })

    it('has 5 steps in the progress bar', () => {
        let Steps = mountedComponent.find('ProgressBar Step')
        expect(Steps.length).toEqual(5)
    })
```

the component itself actually renders 5 steps on a progress bar. The tests are failing to find the expected elements and using enzymes debug the resulting tree just has unnamed elements. I've also tried using enzymes mount but that didn't help. The output of the .debug() is the below.

```
<n percent={75} filledBackground="linear-gradient(to right, #fefb72, #f0bb31)">
        <i transition="scale">
          [function]
        </i>
        <i transition="scale">
          [function]
        </i>
        <i transition="scale">
          [function]
        </i>
        <i transition="scale">
          [function]
        </i>
        <i transition="scale">
          [function]
        </i>
      </n>
```

I keen to understand why these nodes are unnamed, and what is going on.

Comment: What does `console.log(mountedComponent.debug())` print?

Comment: It prints the tree above with the `n` and `i` nodes

Comment: That's weird, never seen it before. What did your component look like when the test was passing, you said? What if you try to log `mountedComponent.html()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the test looked like while it was passing. And I can't seem to get back to a state that passes. The HTML is largely what I would expect.

Comment: No, I meant try logging that command...

Comment: I would also like to see your ProgressBar component.

Comment: The progress bar component is this component from npm https://github.com/pierreericgarcia/react-step-progress-bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218170/discussion-between-steven-fisher-and-k-wasilewski).

Comment: no need to test third party library https://daveceddia.com/what-to-test-in-react-app/

Comment: Well it depends, I don't want to test that the 3rd party lib does what I expect. But I do want to test that I'm providing the components that I expect to the lib given the steps are dependent on the state of my component.